# what is the use of transparent?

Tags: android, transparent, thumbnails

what is the use of transparent...which place its using for it...

Comment: Would it be possible to ask a more vague question?

Comment: sorry new for android application....i am confused....

Comment: Please explain your question more.. it would be easier for us to answer it .

Comment: just what is the use of transparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to add a sub View within a View but not have a background on the sub View, you could use the transparent color.

This can be placed in XML:
android:background="@android:color/transparent"